# Getting Uncaught in (promise) DOMException once chrome and webview is updated

Tags: google-chrome, ionic-framework

I have updated the chrome in my device today after that i am facing the issues for the ionic1 apps which i have created.When i run the app i am getting the error as

```
Getting Uncaught in (promise) DOMException once chrome is updated
```

My Chrome version is 66.0.3359.126
My Android System Webview version is 66.0.3359.126

Does anybody has faced these kind of issues previously

Comment: Include the code that's throwing this exception in your question.

Comment: @Nidhinkumar are you use localforage or otherwise and tell ur device internal stroage details.

Comment: @Ragu i am using localforage as well as my internal storage is 789MB/4.02GB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

- If you use localforage, your device must have **free
  space**  in internal storage because localforage occupy internal storage memory. now **clean your internal storage** it will work fine.

**Solution 2:**

- Use **localstorage** instead of **localforage** .